# How to reorder cells in DoHeatmap plot in Seurat (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I'm plotting a heatmap with Seurat in R

```
require(Seurat)
data <- data.frame(cell1=c(-0.5, 0.5), cell2=c(-0.8, 0.3), cell3=c(2.0, 0.1), cell4=c(1.0, 1.0))
rownames(data) <- c("gene1", "gene2")
test <- CreateSeuratObject(data)
test@scale.data <- data
DoHeatmap(test)
```

And this is what I get

[image: heatmap result]

I want to reorder cells here with custom order.
I have tried `DoHeatmap(test, data.use=<reordered data>)` and `p <- DoHeatmap(…, plot=FALSE)` and then reordering `p$data`, but to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can coerce `p$data$cell` to a factor and specify the levels according to our needs.

```
set.seed(1)
(custom_order <- paste0("cell", sample(4)))
#[1] "cell2" "cell4" "cell3" "cell1"
```

Create the plot and reorder

```
p <- DoHeatmap(test)
p$data$cell <- factor(p$data$cell, levels = custom_order)
p
```

[image]